# New to Beautiful Soup. Need to scrape tables from an online report

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the following data using beautiful soup. I can figure out. Please help.

```
 <TABLE WIDTH=100%>
        <TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="30%">
            <TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="100%">
            <TR>
                <TH COLSPAN="3"><CENTER><B>SUMMARY</B></CENTER></TH>
            </TR>
            <TR><TD>Alberta Total Net Generation</TD><TD>9299</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Net Actual Interchange</TD><TD>-386</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Alberta Internal Load (AIL)</TD><TD>9685</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Net-To-Grid Generation</TD><TD>6897</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Contingency Reserve Required</TD><TD>518</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Dispatched Contingency Reserve (DCR)</TD><TD>552</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Dispatched Contingency Reserve -Gen</TD><TD>374</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Dispatched Contingency Reserve -Other</TD><TD>178</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>LSSi Armed Dispatch</TD><TD>73</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>LSSi Offered Volume</TD><TD>73</TD></TR>

            </TABLE>
```

This is the link I want to scrape.
http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSDReportServlet

I need the Summary, Generation and Interchange table separately. Any help would be great..

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `pd.read_html` + `beautifulsoup` to read the data. Also, use `html5lib` parser when you parse the page (contains malformed tags):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_summary(soup):
    summary = soup.select_one(
        "table:has(b:-soup-contains(SUMMARY)):not(:has(table))"
    )
    summary.tr.extract()
    return pd.read_html(str(summary))[0]


def get_generation(soup):
    generation = soup.select_one(
        "table:has(b:-soup-contains(GENERATION)):not(:has(table))"
    )
    generation.tr.extract()
    for td in generation.tr.select("td"):
        td.name = "th"
    return pd.read_html(str(generation))[0]


def get_interchange(soup):
    interchange = soup.select_one(
        "table:has(b:-soup-contains(INTERCHANGE)):not(:has(table))"
    )
    interchange.tr.extract()
    for td in interchange.tr.select("td"):
        td.name = "th"
    return pd.read_html(str(interchange))[0]


url = "http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSDReportServlet"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html5lib")

print(get_summary(soup))
print(get_generation(soup))
print(get_interchange(soup))
```

Prints:

```
                                       0     1
0           Alberta Total Net Generation  9359
1                 Net Actual Interchange  -343
2            Alberta Internal Load (AIL)  9702
3                 Net-To-Grid Generation  6946
4           Contingency Reserve Required   514
5   Dispatched Contingency Reserve (DCR)   552
6    Dispatched Contingency Reserve -Gen   374
7  Dispatched Contingency Reserve -Other   178
8                    LSSi Armed Dispatch    78
9                    LSSi Offered Volume    82

            GROUP     MC   TNG  DCR
0             GAS  10836  6801   79
1           HYDRO    894   270  233
2  ENERGY STORAGE     50     0   50
3           SOLAR    936   303    0
4            WIND   2269   448    0
5           OTHER    424   273   12
6       DUAL FUEL      0     0    0
7            COAL   1266  1264    0
8           TOTAL  16675  9359  374

               PATH  ACTUAL FLOW
0  British Columbia         -230
1           Montana         -113
2      Saskatchewan            0
3             TOTAL         -343
```

Comment: please explain  the css selectors

Comment: @AlbertoHanna `"table:has(b:-soup-contains(SUMMARY)):not(:has(table))"` this will select `<table>` that contains `<b>` with text `"SUMMARY"` and doesn't contain any inner `<table>` tag.